# comparing two string arrays to check if the entered value is there in the string array

Tags: java

I have two string arrays

```
String[] Mids contains 
MSI
MSU
MSV

String[] sl contains
    MSU
    MSV
    MSS
```

Actual output should be

```
Action 
Action 
Action cannot be set

for(int i=0;i<sl.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<Mids.length;j++){
                    if((sl[i].equals(Mids[j]))){
                       System.out.println("Action");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Action cannot be set");
                    }
                }
            }
```

OUTPUT  which i get

```
Action cannot be set
Action cannot be set
Action cannot be set
Action cannot be set
Action
Action cannot be set
Action
Action cannot be set
Action cannot be set
```

Comment: And now we are expected a) to find out what you really want, b) where you failed, and c) how to fix it? How about you give us more details about what you are trying to accomplish (and why).

Comment: Are you forced to use arrays? What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're iterating over both arrays and always printing if you have found the same value. But you should do this only in the first loop. I changed the for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<sl.length;i++){
   boolean found = false;
   for(int j=0;j<Mids.length;j++){
      if((sl[i].equals(Mids[j]))){
         found = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (found) {
      stdOut.println("Action");
   } else {
      stdOut.println("Action cannot be set");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To say if an element is not found in an array you need to compare it with all the elements. Just because one comparison fails you cannot conclude that it is not found in the array.

Try something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<sl.length;i++){
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j=0;j<Mids.length;j++){
                if((sl[i].equals(Mids[j]))){
                        found = true;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(found) {
                // print found.
        } else {
                // print not found.                                             
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add another printline under the for loop(i) that displays s1 and mids so that you can better understand the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, with fewer lines of code and fewer iterations would be:

```
List<String> midsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Mids));
    for (String string : sl) {
        if (midsList.contains(string)) {
            System.out.println("Action");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Action cannot be set");
        }
    }
```